# Handle spaces in path for cmd

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm building a command to run through cmd.exe. But the command seems to fail due to the space in some directory names.

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(this.phpPath + " " + this.phpUnitPath + " " + itemChecked);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the path between double quotes:

```
string command = "\"" + someFilePathWithSpaces + "\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to pass text with spaces in a command line is to wrap it in quotes like this:

```
app "c:\my apps\blah.exe" "some argument"
```

Try doing something like this:

```
string path = this.phpPath + " " + this.phpUnitPath + " " + itemChecked
string cmd = string.Format("\""{0} {1} {2}"\"", 
    this.phpPath, this.phpUnitPath, itemChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're using `cmd.exe` but you're writing out data to a `Process`'s stdin. I'm assuming that `process` is a `cmd.exe` instance you've started.

A possibly better way would be to use the `/C` switch:

```
C:\Users\Jonathon>cmd /?
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OF
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
...
```

Either way you go, all paths with spaces in them need to be enclosed in quotes.

As a final note, are you sure you even need to be using `cmd.exe` ? Why not just execute the program you actually want to run directly?

Answer (score 0):

Put whatever numbers of partial path in the first array in following statement:

```
var path=String.Join((new[] { this.phpPath, this.phpUnitPath, itemChecked }).Aggregate((a, b) => a+"\x20"+b), new[] { '\"', '\"' });
```